# jQuery if/else unexpected token: punch ({)

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, gruntjs

I've got a little if query. It has to be a bit like Media Queries. In a way it works, but Grunt print out an error called:

> Unexpected token: punc ({).

Here's my jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 800) {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 2,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function () {
                    showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 1,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function () {
                    showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
    }))
    else {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 3,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
            pager: false,
            randomStart: true,
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            controls: true,
            onSliderLoad: function () {
                showSlider();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Tangentially, jQuery's [`resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) cannot be used in an `if()` statement, as it does not return a boolean value. Instead, use it to create a resize listener.

Comment: What is the purpose of that first `if`? My guess is that you don't need/want it there, and that your final `else` block should actually be at the same level as your two other `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say given the limited amount of information you've provided, but I'm pretty sure that this is actually what you want to do.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 480){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 1,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
        else if($(window).width() < 800){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 2,
                maxSlides: 2,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function() {
                    showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 3,
                maxSlides: 3,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This actually didn't print out any error which is good. So thank you, but I've got some problems in my thoughts.

Comment: @runepiper I can help fix your code, but there's not much I can do to help fix your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

On the line above your final else statement, try removing the `}))`.  Hard for me to test, but in my editor it looks like these do not match up with anything and are just extra.  Could be wrong though, worth a shot since I believe you are receiving the equivalence of a syntax error.

Also missing a bracket at the end.  I believe the below code should be syntactically correct, however some changes might need to be made based on how you want to flow through the conditionals, i.e. I'm not clear as to which `if` the `else` belongs to.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).resize(function(){
            if($(window).width() < 800){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                    minSlides: 2,
                    maxSlides: 2,
                    moveSlides: 1,
                    pager: false,
                    randomStart: true,
                    auto: true,
                    autoHover: true,
                    controls: true,
                    onSliderLoad: function() {
                        showSlider();
                    }
                });
            }
            if($(window).width() < 480){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                    minSlides: 1,
                    maxSlides: 1,
                    moveSlides: 1,
                    pager: false,
                    randomStart: true,
                    auto: true,
                    autoHover: true,
                    controls: true,
                    onSliderLoad: function(){
                        showSlider();
                    }
                });
            }
        else {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                minSlides: 3,
                maxSlides: 3,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                randomStart: true,
                auto: true,
                autoHover: true,
                controls: true,
                onSliderLoad: function(){
                    showSlider();
                }
            });
        }
    }});
```